# How to check Network connection with Ionic React?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react, network-connection

I would like to check my Internet connection in my Ionic React application.
All what I find on Internet is for Ionic angular.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ionic with Capacitor u can use the [@capacitor/network](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/network) api.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks,
I find something else ...

```
['load', 'online', 'offline'].forEach(function (e) {
    window.addEventListener(e, () => { props.setNetworkState(navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline") });
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Are you tested it in a real device? window.navigator.onLine works only on the browser but if you target a real device (Android...) it doesn't work.